# How can you join objects without merging vertex groups? (2.79b)

Tags: objects, interface, vertex-groups

everyone. I am using Blender 2.79b, and I am running into trouble. I have a character mesh that I created, and then selectively separated into multiple objects for easy editing (outer skin, teeth, claws, mouth, etc). I created a vertex group for each object, with the same name as the object. Now that I have finished tweaking things, I am attempting to recombine all of the objects as one using Ctrl+J. However, when I do this, all of my vertex groups seem to merge into one, which is screwing with my textures, my UVs, all of it. Is there a way to join objects without actually merging vertex groups? I have searched on Google, asked in FB groups, and looked at the suggested posts on this site for my question title (didn't find anything that actually matched there). Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give them different names. If you have two objects with the same vertex group's names they will merge into one vertex group. If you have objects with different vertex group's names they will stay separated as before.
I hope it helps.

Comment: They are all named differently. Unfortunately, it doesn't matter. As mentioned above, each part is named differently, and has a vertex group named for itself; there are no identical names among vertex groups. For example, I have one object, "OuterSkin", with a vertex group ALSO named "OuterSkin"... but no other object/vertex groups sharing that name. Same with "Claws", "Eyes", "Mouth", "Tongue" and "Teeth". No name duplicates among objects, none among vertex groups. Matching names BETWEEN each object and the vertex group assigned to it, but that is all.

Comment: Than maybe I don't understand question. Because when I am trying to merge two objects with different vertex group's name, groups do not merge into one. Can you clarify what do you mean by merge groups into one? Or even attach blend file.